# Why does my jquery function not work on div in page loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm just starting out with jquery. Already learned some things and like it, but I have been struggling with the following issue for a few days.
I copied the "dialog-confirm"-function from  https://jqueryui.com/. I placed this script between the  tags on my index.php page.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
      $('#scrollpage').height($(window).height() - 250);
  });
  $(window).trigger('resize');

    $('.container').on('click', '.mainmenu', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(data) {
          //alert(data);
          $("#div1").load(url);
        });

        $( this ).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
      $( this ).parent().siblings().removeClass('current_page_item');
  });

  $('.container').on('click', '.rapport', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
        //$(".dialog-confirm").dialog( "open" );

        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        $("#div1").load(url);
      });
  });
});

</script>
```

If i place the matching div in the same index.php page. It works fine, the div pops up.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Blablabla</p>
</div>
```

However when i place the div in a page which is loaded by ajax in the div1, then I cant get it to work.

```
<div class="scrollpage" id="scrollpage">
  <div class="container" class="page" id="div1">

  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is, and how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you mean your divs like: `<div id="div1"><div id="dialog-confirm">...` after ajax load?

Comment: I think so. 
At the time the script is created, the div is not loaded yet. Could that be an issue?

Comment: sharing a fiddle is a great idea here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that your $(document).ready() function executes as soon as the DOM is loaded. This DOM contains just what it is in the html file. At that time, there's no div with an id equal to *'dialog-confirm'*. Loading pieces of HTML with ajax doesn't trigger a DOMReady event. What you've got to do is to call the .dialog() jQuery function AFTER you've loaded the div with Ajax:

```
    $("#div1").load(url, function() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:140,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete all items": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 },
                 Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                 }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your theory makes sense. When I place your code in my script, firebug highlights the row
    $("#div1").load(url, function() {
and says "url is not defined".

If I remove url, there are no more errors, but the script doesnt seem to be triggered.

Comment: I'm sorry for being an idiot :) Placed the code at wrong place, it works like a charm! I'll vote you up as soon as I get my 15 credit points :)

Comment: @skampen I think you can "at least" mark this answer as accepted before having 15 reputation, if it fits your needs. :)

Comment: did it, the live of a newbie is full of obstacles

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens in your program(loading div with ajax):

- First, your script initiates dialog window container by looking an element with id `dialog-confirm`.
- Since, you don't have an element with that id yet, dialog container cannot be prepared.

There are two ways you can make it work:

1. Call `dialog()` after ajax requests,
2. Place `div` statically on page and change content with ajax request.

Solutions:

1- Use the code below instead of `$("#div1").load(url);`

```
    $("#div1").load(url, function(){
       $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
              "Delete all items": function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  },
                  Cancel: function() {
                  $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              }
          }
       });
    });
```

2- Place divs statically on your page:

```
    <div class="scrollpage" id="scrollpage">
       <div class="container" class="page" id="div1">
         <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
            <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Blablabla</p>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Then load just `<p>...` with `$("#dialog-confirm").load(data);` instead of `$("#div1").load(url);`.

Comment: Thanks to you too. Used the first fix, also suggested by @OscarPaz and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery is executed only once after your page is loaded. Then is initiating everything needed for the tool! 
This means every .container is being 'transformed'.
If you later add a new div.container it is not 'transformed' yet. You have to execute the jquery again after your div is appended!